# Flex validator popup at surprising location. Can I tweak it?

Tags: apache-flex, validation

Here's a minimal Flex app that has a validator for the length of a RichEditableText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:NumberValidator id="titleLenValidator"
                            exceedsMaxError="Your text is too long. As a result some of it is not shown."
                            maxValue="60"
                            property="contentHeight"
                            source="{titleLabel}"
                            >
        </mx:NumberValidator>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:RichEditableText id="titleLabel"
                        text="very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long very long "
                        maxHeight="40" width="400"
                        y="400"
                        fontSize="20"
                        >
    </s:RichEditableText>
    <s:Button>
    </s:Button>
</s:Application>
```

The problem is that when the content of the text box is scrolled down the validator is moved up with it, and the end result looks like this:

[image]

How can tweak the location of the validator's popup so that it's not on top of the location of the content but rather right on top the control itself?

Answer (score 1):

for spark forms validation you should wrap RichEditableText into FormItem, in case if you will need some custom layout (e.g. error string in non-default position) - you should create skin for FormItem and change layout inside (e.g. change error string label position)